# TreeView and scrolling to view specific items in the windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview to display some data from a list of 1000000 strings (so 1000000 nodes to be created).

I would want to load only 100 strings at first into the treeview. Then if I scroll down my mouse, the tree will show me the next nodes (20, 50 or even 100 nodes etc).

I can't find a function in treeview to help me do this.

Edit: `// 150000 children as a string[]` takes ~7 minutes to be present in the treeview `tv`

```
tv.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                n.Nodes.Add(child, child, 2, 2);

            }
            tv.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: So how many scrolls are required to reach the bottom of this list? I think that this will not score well in the realm of the best user experience

Comment: 1000000 is the number (just in case =]]). But C#'s current treeview couldn't even handle 100000 =]] in milliseconds (in my case).

Comment: what you are looking for is "virtualization" have a quick research and you will see :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549209/wpf-treeview-virtualization

Comment: Why do you want to add items in this way? Why not add them all at once?

Comment: Thank you, I am working on winform. and fail to add a lot of data to a treeview (it takes 6-9 minutes on my computer to create 150000 leaves in a tree node).

Comment: 1) The ussual way is to add only the __1st and 2nd__ level of nodes so user can see the 1st level __and__ the expansion crosses. Upon expanding a node to next level should be loaded, pretty much like file exploere does it. - 2) if a level contains a large number of nodes, make sure to __create and fill the node standalone__ and only add it to the TV when filled or else it will be very slow!!- 3) __No user can properly work with 100k items of anything__. Try to change the design, maybe by prepending some filter to drill down to the data they actually want to see!

Comment: I did that, but it's strange the treeview seems unable to do fast for me. Please see my edited question above of the small code under consideration.

Comment: Doing it as I said, it takes around 2 seconds to add 100k nodes..: `int count = 100000;
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    node.Nodes.Add("node " + i);
}
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);`

Comment: Adding a random number of ~10 subnodes to each of the 100k nodes brings the count up to ~1M nodes and takes 12 seconds.

Comment: Why do you need to display literally a million nodes to the user? Does the user really need to see all million rows? Why not load them into a list and allow users to filter the ones they need?